# Compact-open topology where domain is discrete or trivial

Tags: general-topology, compactness

> (1) Let $X$ be a discrete space with $|X|=n$. Show that the space of functions $\text{Map}(X,Y)$ with the compact-open topology is homeomorphic to $Y\times Y\times\cdots\times Y$ (n times).
>
> (2) If $X$ has the trivial topology and $Y$ is Hausdorff, identify the space $\text{Map}(X,Y)$.

My thoughts so far: for (1), I know that we have the prebasis (subbasis) given by
$$
S(K,U):=\{f:X\to Y\;|\;f(K)\subseteq U\}
$$
where $K\subseteq X$ is compact and $U\subseteq Y$ is open. Now since $X$ is finite, *every* subset is compact, and thus some of the $S(K,U)$ consist of $S(x,U)$ for $x\in X$. But the product space $Y\times\cdots\times Y$ has prebasis given by all $S(x,U)$, so the $S(K,U)$ at least generate $Y\times Y\times\cdots\times Y$. Does this suffice? How do I know "more stuff" isn't generated by the $S(K,U)$, i.e. how do I know that the $S(K,U)$ generate precisely $Y\times\cdots\times Y$? Is it because each $S(K,U)$ can be written as a finite intersection of the $S(x,U)$?

For (2), I'm really not sure, all I can grasp is that every subset of $X$ is compact since it has the trivial topology, but I'm not sure how to translate this to the $S(K,U)$. How do I use that $Y$ is Hausdorff here? Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, every subset of $X$ is compact, since any open cover is just the whole set. That should make computing the topology rather easy.

Comment: So in that case the prebasis is given by $S(K,U)$ where $K$ is *any* subset of $X$, but what do I do about the $U$? I guess $U$ can be taken to be all of $Y$, so then $S(K,Y)$ is all maps from $K$ to $Y$, but I'm struggling to see what topology this generates.

Comment: So i've figured out that $f$ has to be constant, and now I'd like to write $\{f\}$ as a finite intersection of $S(K,U)$. It would be nice if I could just do $S(X,c)$ where $f(x)=c$ for all $x\in X$, but points are not in general open in $Y$. Am I on the right track?

Comment: I actually was incorrect, my bad. The topology on the set of maps is just the same as the topology of $Y$, with the identification $y\in Y\mapsto f_y$, where $f_y(x)=y$.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes more sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(1)$: as $X$ is finite, you can write $f$ with the image $(y_1,\dots y_n)$. Then the open-compact definition means $y_{i_{1}},\dots y_{i_{k}}\in U$, $\{i_1,\dots,i_k\}=K$, which means $S(K,U)=A_1\times\dots A_n$, $$A_i =\begin{cases}U &\text{if $i\in K$,}\\ X &\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$
That clearly ends the proof.

$(2)$: the hint is understanding which are the continuous maps from trivial topology to Hausdorff spaces. Once you have it, the problem is quite trivial.